# Node.js error in express response not getting produced

Tags: node.js

Here are snippets of index.js and router.

index.js

```
.....

let defaultRoute = require('./routes/default')
app.use('/', defaultRoute)

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
res.status(500);
res.json(err);
.....
```

default.js

```
.....

router.get ('/', function (req, res){

    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function(err) {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        var request = new sql.Request();
        var sqlParams = [];

......
```

If multiple threads hit the call, as soon as I hit sql.connect in second code snippet, error thrown and gets caught by exception listener in index.js. I can see the error but, response never gets the error. Where is it going ? Is there a place for node.js errors ?

BTW the error I can only see in debug mode is 'Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.\n    at Object.connect'. I know that I need to use connection pool. I have the code ready. I just wonder what is rewriting the response or what is gobbling my error.

Reason for my curiosity is- With the code like that I am not seeing the error spitted out in anyway, I can see the error when I have a breakpoint there. But same code on Kubernetes raises Dynatrace problems with detailed error logged. Just trying to understand before I put my code fix with connection pool.

Comment: This is known as a race condition. The error is self-explanatory, close the connection if you do not need it and reopen it when needed.

Comment: It's not recommended to create a connection for every request, you should rather create connection at the startup of the application, and then reuse it for every request.

Comment: I appreciate you answers. As I said, I got that. My question is, why with 'res.json(err)', client is not receiving it ?